# JSP attribute JSON object is dropping escape characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, escaping

I have a server-side controller which is adding an attribute which is a Java object converted to JSON using Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
model.addAttribute("commentObj", mapper.writeValueAsString(commentObject);
```

My commentObject has a field "comments" which contains quotation marks (") that JSON needs to escape. When I do a simple print-out from the JSP of the commentObject, everything looks good:

```
[{"commentId":123,"comments": "this \"test\" is here"}]
```

As you see, the quotes get escaped properly (\").

My problem comes with the javascript on this page that also needs to access this object. So when I run the following:

```
<script>
    var test = ${commentObj};
</script>
```

If I take a look at the 'test' var, the comments field now reads as follows:

```
"this "test" is here" 
vs. 
"this \"test\" is here"
```

This causes a problem because JSON.parse() will throw an error on 'test' because it is not properly formed JSON anymore.

So my question is, how do I manage to get my commentObj into a javascript object while keeping the escape characters so that I can JSON.parse it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, written at the end of a long day while sick and only just realized now that the 'test' var ends up being a fully formed JS object. So I am able to use that.

That said, I still have the question of how that is happening? It seems to me that it should be coming in as a JSON string that I need to call JSON.parse on. Anyone have an explanation?

Comment: At the time you put `commentObj` into your model, it has already been serialized to a JSON string. In your JSP's script tag, you assign it to a variable. It's as if you had assigned a literal javascript array to `var test`. In other words, its javascript type is object, not string. If you had written `var test = '${commentObj}';` then it would be a string. Sure, on the server side in Java, it's a string. But you're assigning an object literal to a javascript variable. Be glad you don't have to parse a string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ca understand how it's being treated as an object on the JS side versus a literal string (if I don't enclose it in quotes) but I still don't understand how JS knows to parse it from JSON to an object without explicit instruction.

Comment: That's just what [javascript does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). If you view the source of your page, you won't see a string, you'll see `var test = [{"commentId":123,"comments": "this \"test\" is here"}];`. It was the value of a java string that was used in writing an html document, which included your script tag and the variable value.